# Why is my HTML Element and Form not being recognized by the browser?

Tags: html, css, forms

This may seem like I'm missing something super simple, but I cannot for the sake of me figure this out.

I have a `<form>` wrapped inside a `<div class="form">`, and for some reason, in the browser, the form, and the div, have a height of 0, and all the content is overflow. When I inspect the document from the browser, the browser does not recognize this div or form.

Here's the problem area here:

Also, you can inspect it at this website here: [Web page](https://www.fralinpickups.com/rewinds-repairs-form.html)

```
<div class="form">
    <form>
            <div class="contact">
                <label for="first">First Name:</label>
                <input id="first" type="text" placeholder="First Name"><br>   

                <label for="last">Last Name:</label>
                <input id="last" type="text" placeholder="Last Name"><br>

                <label for="tel">Phone Number:</label> 
                <input id="tel" type="tel" placeholder="(###) ###-####"><br>

                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input id="email" type="email">
            </div>



            <div class="address">
                <label for="address-1">Address</label>
                <input id="address-1" type="text" placeholder="Address Line 1"><br>   

                <label for="address-2">Address, Line 2</label>
                <input id="address-2" type="text" placeholder="Address Line 2"><br>

                <label for="city">City:</label>
                <input id="city" type="text" placeholder="City"><br>

                <label for="state">State:</label>
                    <select id="state">
                        <optgroup>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select></br>

                <label for="zip">Zip Code:</label>
                <input id="zip" type="text" placeholder="01234">
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: your submit button is outside of the `form` element. is that what you are referring to?

Comment: This form is not designed to be submitted - I have a `<button>` element at the bottom of the page that has a `onclick="printForm()` that prints the form only for sending in with a customer's package.

Comment: @Sackadelic, if you don't need to submit the data back to your site, you don't need the `form` element, and your CSS doesn't have a `form` class, which might be confusing the browser.

Comment: it works perfectly for me on FireFox, I don't see any problem

Comment: @comptercarguy, thank you for this tip. This is my first form.

Answer (score 1):

Does you talk about that the div and form have `height:0` and the content overflow?

If so, it is because the content divs have `float` css attributes. to fi it, you have to add at the end of the contents div with style `clear:both`

```
<div class="form">
    <form>
        <div class="contact">
          ...
        </div>

        <div class="address">
           ...
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Tukachinski, Thank you for your help with that. I've amended the CSS rules, but still, my `<div class="form">` isn't showing. Any other ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I just check it and it's work. what you want to be shown?

Comment: Ah it was a caching issue. All is working now. Thank you all, helpful humans.